# Finding coefficients of x in a string

Tags: python, string-parsing, algebra

I am trying to make an algebra solver, so I have to find the coefficients of x in an expression. Currently this is the code I have to take an input:

```
equation = input("Enter equation: ")
LHS, RHS = equation.split("=")[0], equation.split("=")[1]

##Remove whitespaces
LHS, RHS = LHS.replace(" ",""), RHS.replace(" ","")
```

Now I want to get the coefficients of x in the expressions LHS and RHS, how can I do this?
And also, the coefficients may not be just numbers but they may be of the form (2*3+4)x. I think this can be done using the eval() function but I don't know how to apply it.

Note: I want to do this with plain python, without using any modules which are not built-in.

Comment: Can you give an example of a valid input and the expected output?

Comment: @Thaer A If the input was "2-(2+4*5)x +3x" then output would be ["2-(2+4*5)", "3"] or any other variable containing the coefficients.

Answer (score 0):

In case it's only one variable and thus only one coefficient you could divide the respective variable/site by x.
Taking your example:

> (2*3+4)x

dividing by x gives us the coefficient:

> (2*3.4)

If that's not the approach you want to take, you could also convert the expression into a string and exclude "x", as such:

```
coefficientLHS = LHS.replace("x", "")
```

However, you should use this cautious as you might have algebra expressions in front of your variable, so regex implementation would be advisable.

Another approach would be to use the module `Poly`:

```
x = symbols("x")
coefLHS = Poly(LHS, x)
coefLHS.coeffs()
```

Comment: Yes there will be algebra expressions in front of the x, so this approach won't work without some extra processing.

Comment: What about using the module Poly? I edit my solution, take a look at it. :)